# What is the method to manage network interfaces in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: networking, upgrade, network-manager

After upgrading two instances of an older Ubuntu (10.10 and 11.04) to 12.04, I notice an apparent conflict between the way my network interfaces were previously managed and the new methodology, which apprently is extremely "Network-Manager-Centric."

It seems that my previous configurations, stored in /etc/network/interfaces, continue to work, but tools like 'dhclient' not longer function as expected. Now, in order to re-configure the interface between a static IP and a DHCP IP, I've discovered the best solution is to comment out all but the 'lo' adapter in the /etc/network/interfaces file, and just perform all my configuraion changes with Network Manager.

My question is 2-fold:

1. Is this expected behavior, as part of some kind of long-term plan to exclusively use Network Manager?
2. Is there documentation which describes the current state of network interface management in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the networkmanager, take a look at this [link](http://dijks.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/how-to-disable-network-manager-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise/).

But why does `dhclient` not work (or is not working as expected)? Have you altered the `dhclient.conf`?

`dhclient <NIC>` "should" almost always work.

Comment: Previously, 'dhclient eth0' ALWAYS worked. Now, it produces the message 'RTNETLINK answers: File exists' and the old static settings remain. As far as I can tell, I'm not the only one who's encountered this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1928138

Comment: Send in a bug report. It should work.